# How to take a GEO-TIFF and turn it into map via mapbox?

Tags: gis, mapbox

When uploading a GEO-TIFF file to Mapbox to create a tileset, it is being displayed in Black and White? I would expect it to have the same colors as the TIF when viewed in any other viewer?

How do you create a tileset with a GEO-TIFF to use it as a base map in MapBox?

My ultimate goal is to use this GEO-TIFF and then dynamically lay lat/long points on it, but I need to get the map looking correct first.

Comment: Have a look at gis.stackexchange, which might be more suited for this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Geotiff+mapbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zizi from mapbox support provied this amazing answer that I wanted to share here. This did solve the issue. I don't fully understand how or why it worked, but it worked!

You will need to install Rasterio to transform your raster tiles
Use the following command to expand your tile to RGB: 
gdal_translate -co TILED=TRUE -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -expand RGB INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif

(this will leave you with a raster tile with a black background.)

To make your raster tile transparent, use the following command:

rio calc "(asarray (take a 1) (take a 2) (take a 3))" --co compress=lzw --co tiled=true --co blockxsize=256 --co blockysize=256 --name a=INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif

Next, run this command to set NoData values to zero:

rio edit-info --nodata 0 INPUT.tif

and then upload the resulting tile to your Mapbox account (I've included before and after screenshots below).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when your geotiff does not meet the criteria specified here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/#tiff-uploads